# Magento: Change product name while added into cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

i tried below code but can't solve below code

**path :** `magento/app/code/local/ Ajax/ProductAdjust/Model/Observer.php`

```
     <?php
    class Ajax_ProductAdjust_Model_Observer
   {

       public function updateName(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {

        $events = $observer->getEvent();
        $item = $events->getQuoteItem();
        $item->setName('Ians custom product name');
        $item->save();
      }
   }

  ?>
```

**config file:** `Ajax/ProductAdjust/etc/config.xml`

```
  <config>
       <modules>
         <Ajax_ProductAdjust>
           <version>1.0.1</version>
         </Ajax_ProductAdjust>
       </modules>
       <global>
           <models>
             <Ajax_ProductAdjust>
               <class>Ajax_ProductAdjust_Model</class>
             </Ajax_ProductAdjust>
           </models>
           <events>
              <sales_quote_add_item>
                  <observers>
                     <ajax_productadjust_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Ajax_ProductAdjust_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updateName</method>
                     </ajax_productadjust_model_observer>
                 </observers>
              </sales_quote_add_item>
          </events>
      </global>
     </config>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you out, we need a bit more information. have a look at this help-topic for how to write a great question that people will want to help you answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sir,what u need from my question exactly ? please give me some hint code for solve my question

Comment: I am a "ma'am", not a sir :) Also - please read the above link. It will tell you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: are u sure your observer method id getting called